# Explain GvrPointerInputModule.pointer in the foloowing code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, daydream

I am adding the following line of code in my script to enable controller support for unity VR game which is being played in google daydream. Without this code, the controller is not showing in the final build of the game

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject controllerMain;
    public GameObject controllerPointer;
    private void Start()
    {   
    controllerMain.SetActive(true);
    controllerPointer.SetActive(true);
    GvrPointerInputModule.Pointer = 
    controllerPointer.GetComponentInChildren<GvrLaserPointer>();//3
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me why I need to enable controllermain and controller during gamelay they are not disabled in the hierarchy.
And explain the 3rd line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `controllerMain` and `controllerPointer` variables are just references to [GvrControllerMain](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/reference/prefab/GvrControllerMain) and [GvrControllerPointer](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/reference/prefab/GvrControllerPointer) GameObject prefabs respectively. GvrControllerPointer provides built-in laser pointer used for raycasting. GvrControllerMain is required to use the Daydream controller.

Calling `controllerMain.SetActive(true)` will activate `GvrControllerMain`. The-same thing applies to GvrControllerPointer when you call call `SetActive` on it. Both of these should be activated when running daydream. This is why the activating and de-activating of them happens during run-time because that's when you can determine if this is a daydream device or not.

`GvrPointerInputModule.Pointer` is used to set the pointer type. There is a `GvrLaserPointer` and `GvrReticlePointer`. In your example, you were telling the Gvr module to use `GvrLaserPointer` and is a laser visual that helps users locate their cursor when its not directly in their field of view.